# Tools for sharing apk and ipa files in a company

Tags: file-management, file-sharing

I am looking for (free or not) tools for sharing mobile apps (i.e. runnable programs for Android and iOS) produced by my company so that any authorized stakeholders can access these files and search for a specific build filtering by criteria like environment (Dev, Val, Prod), version (1.1, 1.2 ...), platform (Android, iOS) and any other tags which could be needed.

I do **not** want to share source code but only the .ipa and .apk files.

The tool should just enable the user to download the needed mobile apps.

Do you have any idea of some tools for this?